# Directing a folder outside of it's parent folder or making an include to just the folder PHP

Tags: php, directory, include

So I have an admin folder with pages that are supposed to be secured, but one folder I have in there needs to be linked to a file outside of the admin folder.

It looks something like this:

```
admin folder >

    uploads folder 
    insert.php 

index.php
```

I upload pictures on the insert.php and they get pathed like so:

`$base_upload_path = "uploads/";`

But I also need them to show up on the index.php page as well. I've tried to include the uploads folder on the index.php page or even direct the path outside of the admin folder but nothing has worked so far.

If anyone could give suggestions I'd very much appreciate it as I'm pretty new to PHP.

insert.php

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/validate.php");
include("includes/file_utils.php");
include("includes/image_utils.php");


$result_image = null;
$isPostRequest = false;
$fileErrors = "";
$isValidForm = false;
$base_upload_path = "uploads/";
$successfulImageSave = false;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  $isPostRequest = true;

    $id = null;
    $img_name = "";
    $thumb_name = "";
    $title = "";
    $description = "";
    $img_type = "";

  if (isset($_FILES['the_file']) &&
      isset($_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE']) &&
      isset($_POST['title']) &&
      isset($_POST['description'])) {

      $max_upload_size = validate_number($_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE']);
      $title = validate_string($_POST['title']);
      $description = validate_string($_POST['description']);


      $isValidFile = is_valid_file($_FILES['the_file']);


      if ($max_upload_size != false &&
          $title != false &&
          $description != false &&
          $isValidFile != false) {
        $isValidForm = true;

      } else {

        $fileErrors = get_file_error($_FILES['the_file']);
      }


      if ($isValidForm) {
        $fileName = $base_upload_path.$_FILES['the_file']['name'];

        $isMoved = move_image_to_upload_folder($_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name'], $fileName);


        if ($isMoved) {

          $new_file_name = create_thumbnail($fileName, $_FILES['the_file']['type']);

          if ($new_file_name != false) {
            $successfulImageSave = save_to_database($fileName, $new_file_name, $title, $description, $_FILES['the_file']['type']); 
          }
        }
      }
  }
}

$images = get_images();

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include("admin/includes/db.php");
include("admin/includes/validate.php");
include("admin/includes/file_utils.php");
include("admin/includes/image_utils.php");
include("admin/uploads/");

$images = get_images();

$query = "SELECT img_name, thumb_name, title, description, img_type FROM image_gallery;";

$query_result = mysqli_query($db, $query)


?>
```

Comment: If you can add the actual code snippet. It would be more helpful.

Comment: For sure, it's a bit long though!

Comment: I hope I didn't post too much, thanks in advance.